# iOS8 issue - UIView drawRect is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios8

I have a very simple `UIView`, that is only drawing a triangle. It implements a `UIView drawRect` method that is drawing a figure. It is working fine on iOS7, but when I run the same code on iOS8 it is not even called. Any ideas what has changed on iOS8? My code in nutshell:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@end

@implementation MyView
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // draw things
}
@end

myView = [MyView new];
[self addSubview:myView];
```

**Update**
My view hierarchy: `UIViewController View->Custom UILabel->MyView`

It is an error message bubble, and my view is a beak pointing to something.

I have used a new UI debugging tool, but it is not visible there. Init method is called, `drawRect` is not. Something must have changed in iOS8, because iOS7 is calling `drawRect`.

**Update 2**
Of course I'm using constraints (and `Masonry` pod), and this is why I did not specify the frame.

```
[myView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(make.superview.mas_bottom);
    make.centerX.equalTo(make.superview);
    make.width.equalTo(@10.0f);
    make.height.equalTo(@5.0f);
}];
```

I have also tried adding `[myView setNeedsDisplay]` in various places, but it didn't help.

Comment: Any more informations about how your view is introduced in view hierarchy ? Have you checked view hierarchy with the new debugging tool, to find out where is your view?

Comment: @Vinzzz Updated the question. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Ok... so you're using this MASConstraintMaker... Maybe the iOS 8 bug comes from that class ?

Comment: @Vinzzz It is possible, but I fixed this differently, please note my post. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem finally solved. I'm not sure what exactly caused the issue (`Masonry` [constraints framework] or iOS8 changes to `UILabel`), but the solution was to change the view hierarchy. I created another `UIView` that contains both `UILabel` and my `UIView` (drawn beak) instead of adding the `UIView` to `UILabel` as subview. Now `drawRect` method is called both on iOS7 and iOS8.

**Previous hierarchy:**
`UIViewController View->Custom UILabel->MyView`

**New hierarchy:**
`UIViewController View->Container UIView->Custom UILabel & MyView`

To sum up, if your `drawRect` method is not called on iOS8, and you are adding some `UIView` to `UILabel` as subview, try to use some container which will contain both `UIView` and `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important detail missing in your approach.  You need to specify a frame that determines the origin and size of your view.  This can be done with the `initWithRect` method of `UIView`, or you can set the frame after allocation/initialization.  Since you have a custom `init` method already I would do the following:

```
myView = [MyView new];
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,100.0,100.0);
[self addSubview:myView];
```

This will draw your custom view with an origin point of (0.0,0.0) and a width and height of 100.0.

Furthermore, adding a call to `setNeedsDisplay` should force the `drawRect` method to be called if you are still having trouble:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm of course using constraints, so I don't have frames in my code. Sorry, forget to write about this. Already updated the question.

Comment: You may want to try a call to [self.view layoutSubviews] to ensure your constraints are being processed and rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `myView`'s superview property `clipToBounds = NO`, and that `myView` rect is on screen