# My UIView with core graphics not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom class extending UIView that uses core graphics. currently it should simply show red field.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

This UIView is within another view in my storyboard. 
If i just put a new view using my custom UIView class somewhere within parent view it shows there when i run my app, however i want to position it using code.

parentview .h file:

```
@interface UserProfile : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCustomUIVew *redField;
@end
```

parentview .m file:

```
@implementation UserProfile
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
[redField setFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, width, height)];
```

but when i do this my custom UIView isn't showing at all.

Comment: Is drawrect even called? Please check using a breakpoint.

Comment: @ZeMoon You are right, it i doesn't call. Do you know how do i fix this ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038336/ios8-issue-uiview-drawrect-is-not-called